# How to efficiently check conditions on two columns and perform operation on third column in python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have three columns with thousands of rows. Numbers in column 1 and 2 change from 1 to 6. I desire to check combinations of numbers in both column 1 and 2 to divide the value in column 3 by a certain value.

```
1     2    3.036010    
1     3    2.622544    
3     1    2.622544    
1     2    3.036010    
2     1    3.036010
```

Further, column 3 will be divided by same number if values of column 1 and column 2 are swapped. For example, for 1 2 and 2 1 combinations, column 3 may be divided by same value. My present approach does the job, but I would have to write several conditions manually. What could be more efficient way to perform this task? Thanks in advance!

```
my_data = np.loadtxt('abc.dat')

for row in my_data:    
    if row[0] == 1 and row[1] == 2:
        row[3]/some_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy offers `np.where` which allows for *vectorized* test:

```
result = np.where(data[:, 0] == data[:, 1], data[:, 2]/some_value, data[:, 2])
```

or if you want to change the array in place:

```
data[:, 2] = np.where(data[:, 0] == data[:, 1], data[:, 2]/some_value, data[:, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mask for this:

```
import numpy as np
my_data = np.column_stack([np.random.randint(1, 6, (1000, 2)), np.random.randn(1000)])
some_value = 123

mask = my_data[:, 0] == my_data[:, 1]
# divide 
my_data[mask, 2] /= some_value
```

output in `my_data`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine some conditions like your code. you can use operator `&` for *and* or `|` for *or* in `np.where`:

```
cond1 = my_data[:, 0] == 1                    # cond is a masked Boolean array for where the first condition is satisfied
cond2 = my_data[:, 1] == 2
some_value = 10
indices = np.where(cond1 & cond2)[0]          # it gets indices for where the two conditions are satisfied
# indices = np.where(cond1 | cond2)[0]        # it gets indices for where at least one of the masks is satisfied
result = my_data[:, 2][indices] / some_value  # operation is done on the specified indices
```

and if you want to modify the 2nd column in place, as [Ballesta answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71627280/13394817)

```
my_data[:, 2][indices] = my_data[:, 2][indices] / some_value
```

`np.logical_and` and `np.logical_or` are the other modules that can handle these such conditions, too; These modules must be used as `np.logical_and.reduce` and `np.logical_or.reduce` if conditions are more than two.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started) is more suitable for this task, you can define conditions and apply them to tabular data without any explicit loop.

Comment: numpy may be enough here...

Comment: @SergeBallesta and bare python too... , but is a new user, and I think pandas is easier to use for operation with tabular data.

Comment: numpy is the underlying part of pandas so a vectorized numpy loop is much more efficient than a bare Python one. I agree with you that Pandas would be more *natural* here because it looks more like tabular data that a true 2D array. But IMHO, your answer does not pay attention to the fact that numpy allows to do this task with no explicit loop either... (I did not downvote anyway, because your advice is relevant, even if I wonder whether it would not fit better as a comment)